# Android 3.0 compatibility definition document?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, opengl-es-2.0

I am looking for Android 3.0's CCD (compatibility definition document), mainly to confirm if OpenGL ES 2.0 support is a common spec across all Honeycomb devices.

Unfortunately the official download site for CCDs seems to omit Android 3.0:
http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html

Can anyone point me to an official resource that states whether OpenGL ES 2.0 support is optional or mandatory on Android 3.0?

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 is mandatory as of 3.0 (it's required for hardware acceleration of the UI and RenderScript.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 is mandatory as of 3.0 (it's required for hardware acceleration of the UI and RenderScript.)

Comment: Coming from you, I guess I can consider this an almost official answer ^^. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So Google has downplayed 3.0 and has stressed the fact that they didn't want people becoming too attached to Honeycomb because it was incomplete. My advise would be to skip 3.0 and go straight to Ice Cream Sandwich. I know this isn't the best answer, but from everything I've seen I feel this would be the approved solution.

Comment: Android OS segmentation stats certainly seem to reflect that 3.x represents an almost negligible % of overall market share. http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html